# Best method for split screen layout when there's no unique container

Tags: html, css

I've to do a split screen layout (i.e. showing the content half on left, half on the right), but I'm having problems because there's not a unique container to hold the contents.

EDIT: Another possible solution is refactoring the HTML code to look like the standard cases for applying the split-layout.

[Here](https://ibb.co/V2zHVf9) is an image about how it should be.

I tried float, but seems not working.

```css
.column-a_left {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.column-right1, .column-right2 {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <section class="section-a">
        <header>
            <div class="key-wrapper column-left">
                <img src="https://imgur.com/a/ZzN8zkc" alt="a man with a key" class="key">
            </div>

            <div class="column-right1">
                <svg width="120" height="35" class="logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><path  id="a" d="M.01.021h67.924V34.93H.01z"/> *numbers* </svg>
                <div class="section-a__icons">
                    <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
                    <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
                    <i class="far fa-envelope"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>

        <div class="section-a_left-align column-right2">
            <!-- content -->

            <div class="wrapper-a">
                <a href="#" class="section-a__a">Privacy Policy.</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
```

Comment: On my edit I just added a snippet. I suggest you to upload your image to Imgur and use the link. This way the snippet will really works, helping people better understand your question.

Comment: And I note that your SVG syntax is wrong. `<svg width="120" height="35" class="logo" *numbers* </svg>` it's missing one `>` right after `*numbers*`. As I don't know is your code is really like that or is just the snippet, I didn't fixed it.

Comment: Thanks for adding that image, but adding the image from `img/illustration-main.svg` helps too. Your snippet should be similar as possible to your actual result.

Comment: Sorry, but the imgs are svg files and are not supported it seems! Also I don't know where to insert them to let you snippet work!

Comment: Try to convert SVG to PNG / JPG using [that](https://svgtopng.com/) website. Also, just change `src="img/illustration-main.svg` to `src="link/to/imgur"` on your `<img />` tag.

Comment: Tried to convert but it destroys the svg image.

Comment: Try a different website to convert and to upload that SVG, plz.

Comment: I uploaded the img, but I don't know the syntax for showing it.

Comment: Post a comment with your link to the image, I edit it for you.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/ZzN8zkc

Comment: I just overwrote `link/to/imgur/ZzN8zkc` to the link you sent me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%'
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="key-wrapper column-left">
        <img src="img/illustration-main.svg" alt="a man with a key" class="key">
    </div>

    <div class="column-right1">
        <svg width="120" height="35" class="logo" *numbers* </svg>
        <div class="section-a__icons">
            <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
            <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
            <i class="far fa-envelope"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

The  element is containing the 2x columns, just use it as the parent element and apply your css needed there.

Comment: We're happy with your answer, but adding a explanation about **what you changed** and **why you changed** is a good idea! :)

Comment: There is also the column-right2 to add. How we deal with it? The header is containing only column-right1!

Comment: for that use section-a as the container parent and header and column-right2 as the children